# Windows Cluster Communication Issues

Tags: failover, failovercluster

When I first created a windows cluster (with a Cloud Witness if it matters), everything went smoothly. Then something went wrong with the communication and I had to destroy the cluster.

Now, when I try to create a new cluster and add a second node, I get a message the following message:

> Cluster service on node jupiter2 did not reach the running state. The
>   error code is 0x5b4. For more information check the cluster log and
>   the system event log from node jupiter2. This operation returned
>   because the timeout period expired.

It then rolls it back. This happens even when I create two brand new servers with the firewalls turned off. I have even created two servers in the same hyper-v host with an internal network to eliminate the possibility of my switch interfering. Same issue.

I have tried all of the basic troubleshooting ideas that I can think of - since the issue still occurs with two brand new machines it would seem like there is a GPO or something else in active directory causing the issue - but I'm out of ideas.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Does the old cluster object still exist in active directory?

Comment: @MDMarra - Nope, I cleaned it all up.  I have also tried creating a cluster with a different name as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having DOS protection turned on in my Ubiquiti EdgeSwitch.  Now that it's disabled, it is all working.